# algorithm to merge x lists of y elements to a cap of z elements each

Tags: php, algorithm, math, merge

basically i need some algorithm that fits into the following problem:

i have 5 lists: 10, 30, 40, 40 and 50 elements each
there is a cap of 80 elements
what i want to achieve now, is this:
3 lists: 10, 80 and 80 elements

40 and 40 merge to 80 and 30 and 50 merge to 80, the list with 10 elements is left as the third resulting list
meaning i want to somehow merge all lists, but with a cap of 80 elements, so i really only have as many lists as i really need

this is not a question of sorting but only to merge
it is not possible to split lists up, the elements of a list should always keep together

hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: to clarify, the goal is minimize the number of final lists after merging, and not necessarily fill as many as possible to all the way to 80? They probably correlate strongly, but I think they're a slightly different goals. Anyway, I'd love to see how this is solved.

Comment: it should fill up the lists to 80 elements if possible, using a minimum number of lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) .. it's an NP-hard problem, so you can't achieve this quickly without some heuristic.  The wikipedia page has some code that may be able to help you -- now that you have a name for it maybe you can search more.